# Serialize the contents of a property, but not the property name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

The C# class listed below produces this XML:

```
<Standardize><TestString>Some Data</TestString></Standardize>
```

However, what I'd like is this:

```
<Standardize>Some Data</Standardize>
```

In other words, I want the contents of the TestString property to show up in the XML, but I don't want the TestString property to be listed as an element.  Can I add some attributes to make this happen?

```
   /// <Serialized C# Class/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://test.com/Services/1")]
    public partial class Standardize {


        private string testField;


        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.None, IsNullable=true, ElementName=null)]
        public string TestString {
            get {
                return testField;
            }
            set {
                testField;= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know the full answer, but I think what it will amount to is implementing `ToString` on `Standardize` to return `testField`, and then using some attribute to say that `Standardize` is just a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorate `TestString` with [`XmlText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) instead of `XmlElement`.